# How to insert data into firebase database for each activity in same userID - Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

i am trying to create a social app where profile user has different activity and the image has different activity. When trying to create data in the firebase database it's going well but i am not sure how to put under one same user ID for one user.

My database ref  code looks like this

```
mDatabaseReference = mDatabase!!.reference.child("Users").push() --- RegisterActivity
```

to save data i used

```
val db =  mDatabaseReference.child(userId)
```

My question is how to save data for next activities like profile and image activity under the same userId. How to trigger database ref the same value to update the next activity values.

[Database Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sa4X2.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To store data for each user, you typically create a structure like this:

```
Users
   $uid1
      property1: ....
      property2: ....
   $uid2
      property1: ....
      property2: ....
```

And to build such a structure, you use:

```
val user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser
user?.let {
    val uid = user.uid

    userReference = mDatabase!!.reference.child("Users").child(uid)

    userReference.child("property1").setValue("value of property1");
}
```

---

If you want to keep a list of items for each user, you'd do that with:

```
userReference.child("listIfItems").push().setValue("new item in list");
```

If you're heading in this last direction though, please take a moment to read the Firebase documentation on [structuring data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/structure-data), specifically the section on [flattening data structures](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/structure-data#flatten_data_structures). The recommended structure for storing say user profiles, and a list of data for each user, would be:

```
Profiles
   $uid1
      property1: ....
      property2: ....
   $uid2
      property1: ....
      property2: ....
Items
   $uid1
      item1: ....
      item2: ....
   $uid2
      item1: ....
      item2: ....
```

Comment: i tried to implement the solution but facing same issue. Users -->pushid-->userId-->values and again under Users with same userId  two more childs created. i need to save items with single PushId and UserId

Comment: I'm unfortunately not sure what you're doing to cause that behavior, which is why I explained *how* Firebase works in my answer. I recommend reading [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and updating your question to include a more complete (but still minimal) snippet that reproduces the problem.

Comment: I have updated my question and also attached screenshot of database structure

Comment: That edit is nothing like what I showed in my answer. Please study carefully how I set the value of `userReference`, as it includes the user's ID in the path, which you fail to do.